# Can the masonry on the outside of our fireplace be encapsulated, or must it be rebuilt?

Tags: fireplace, brick, masonry, encapsulation

During the inspection on a prospective home, inspection revealed the fireplace needs to be rebuilt bottom to top. There are cracks allowing moisture in. The estimate from the first fireplace contractor was very high, accordingly! However, the realtor is worried that the seller might balk. Our realtor is having an estimate done regarding not rebuilding the fireplace but encapsulating it. Is this ok in the Indiana climate? Or is this putting a bandaid on a huge problem that can cause larger issues for us later?

Comment: Recommending a rebuild imagine it is quite bad, not something redoing the mortar will fix.  With a fireplace you also need to worry about smoke and carbon monoxide(poison, kills people) gas.

Comment: That is a great point, and one I had overlooked. thank you

Comment: Also need to worry about the fireplace just collapsing if it is bad enough.  They are very heavy and can hurt more than stepping on a lego block at night.  Pictures of the fireplace might give the experts some ideas.

Comment: This sounds like one of those things where the inspection was very valuable. Sometimes beautiful houses have critical defects. Think hard about walking away.

Comment: Without photos, I don't think even experts here can try to guess. You can't tell them what you don't know you should look for.

Comment: Agreed, I also wasn't at the Inspection, thankfully the person we chose, was able to detail the fireplace as a major defect. I really am concerned now after finding out our realtor wants to quick fix the issue with encapsulation....which I know nothing about. Chimney Safety institute has given me some contractors to call.....

Comment: The contractors should be able to do a better inspection and suggest repair, than your inspector can.  It is the contractors field of expertise(or should be) while your inspector is more general knowledge, while good can't know everything.